# Analyse runtime of my algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I am working on creating some algorithms for a course, both of which are for the vertex cover problem.

For the first part I created an algorithm that does the work via brute force, it creates every possible combination of vertices, removes sets that are not covers, then analyses them. This size I already have.

The second part is the same brute force with an added heuristic, where I eliminate the lower portion of combos that are unlikely to make a cover based on the number of edges.

Since both of these do work on the sum of all base elements in the `combos` I need to understand the size of said list.

The graphs are randomly generated with integers for vertices and edges created randomly from pairs of vertices.

```
combos = [] 
vertices = [1, 2, 3,...] 
edges = [(1, 2), (2, 3),...] 
E = len(edges)
V = len(vertices)
```

Brute force

```
for x in range(1, V+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(vertices, X):
        combos.append(subset)

sum = 0
for i in combos:
    for j in i:
        sum += 1
```

The sum of brute force is:

[image]

Heuristc:

```
for x in range(ceil((V**2)/E), V+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(vertices, X):
        combos.append(subset)

sum = 0
for i in combos:
    for j in i:
        sum += 1
```

The sum as I thought it would end up being:

[image]

However, my test runs are not matching up for heuristic, brute force is matching up.

Sample runs:

```
V   E   Brute Heuristic
5   10  80    25
6   11  192   36
7   17  448   294
8   23  1024  792
9   25  2304  1467
10  36  5120  4660
```

Comment: please post your code producing the given output.

Comment: and also add some information on how you came up with the values of `E` in your test data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was doing my math formula wrong, the heuristic is not the sum of all V minus the sum of the lower end. It is the sum from the lower end to all V:

[image]

I do not know exactly why this works and my original does not, since logically the other one is just an expanded version of this one.